# Trying to auto-register a Nagios NSCA client

Tags: linux, puppet, nagios

I am setting up Nagios monitoring using NSCA to report in from monitored hosts and all monitoring is using passive checks.  Currently the monitored hosts each have a configuration file in the nagios etc folder that defines their address, hostgroups, etc.

To ease the addition of new hosts and the ability to spin up dynamic environments, **I am trying to come up with a way to automatically register new monitored hosts.**

Our nagios environment is brand new, so we're open to various approaches.  Our environments also have GitHub Enterprise and Puppet, which I have a feeling could be used in a solution and we'd like to leverage.  The servers are hosted in AWS.

We are only using Nagios Core, not Nagios XI.

Comment: [This thread at the Nagios support forums](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29606&p=113997)  was the first result Google handed me.  Maybe you need to work on your Google-fu... or explain your problem better. [`If you need to scan for new hosts, you could just run the Auto-Discovery Wizard in Nagios XI. If your goal is to manage hosts/services from the CLI, you could following the steps, outlined in our "Automated Host Management" document.`](http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Automated_Host_Management.pdf)

Comment: I should have clarified that we are not using Nagios XI and only using Nagios Core.  We're using NSCA (not NRPE), and as far as I'm aware, you still need to have an entry on the Nagios Core for the passive checks to be processed by the monitoring server.

Comment: Why only passive checks?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if OP would still care about this question six years later, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this there's a tool for converting passive checks into new hosts. It works by watching the Nagios log for errors from passive checks associated with an unknown host and creating the host.

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/Radar--2D-add-hosts-and-services-automatically/details